# Producing 'structurally reconciled' forecasts (e.g. revenue = price * volume)

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I recently learned about [Hierarchical Forecasting](https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html) and that this principle can be applied across hierarchies, cross-sectional groups or temporal aggregations. Independent Forecasts are created and the reconciled.

In my current problem, some hierarchies are present, but there are also *structural relations* between the time series, that should result in coherent forecasts as well. As a specific example there are revenue, price and volume time series. The revenue forecast should correspond to the product of the price and volume forecasts.

Either the revenue forecast fixed (top down) and price and volume should be reconciled with it or all three series are forecasted, but in a coherent manner. Both approaches would seem meaningful.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing optimizing a model subject to linear constraints.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But how do I integrate these constraints into the hierarchical modeling framework. Can a upper level time series (revenue) be forced to equal the product of two lower level time series (price and volume)?

Comment: Does it make sense to *forecast* prices, or are prices *set*?

Comment: The prices can and should also be forecasted.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.

First off, if prices can be set, and all we are forecasting is unit sales and total revenue, then the problem is straightforward: simply use the prices in the summation matrix, instead of ones. Then, for instance, we can reconcile unit sales forecasts $\hat{y}_1$ and $\hat{y}_2$ of two different products with prices $p_1$ and $p_2$ with a total revenue forecast $\hat{r}$ by using the summation matrix

$$ S=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ p_1 & 0 \\ 0 & p_2 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Using similar logic, we can address "mixed" hierarchies, where some nodes stand for total unit sales, and others for total revenue. Or we could do multiple runs to do a scenario analysis of forecasts, for different price scenarios.

The problem is that this approach considers the entries in the summation matrix as fixed. They will not be changed during the reconciliation step.

One alternative would be to work on a log scale. Since revenue is price times unit sales, $r=py$, we have

$$ \log r = \log (py) = \log p+ \log y. $$

So we could, for instance, stack unit sales and price forecasts for a product, and reconcile those, on a log scale.

One problem with this is that we can't add the revenue from multiple products any more. Unless, that is, we are willing to subject the separate revenue forecasts (from a log reconciliation as above) and a total revenue forecast to its very own reconciliation step. And perhaps then plug the results back into the bottom level log reconciliation. It might be worthwhile trying this iterative approach and seeing whether it at least converges.

Incidentally, one advantage of the log approach is that we don't need to worry about negative prices or unit sales forecasts.

The other problem is that reconciliation may not make a lot of sense on a log scale. Point forecasting is equivalent to extracting a single one-number summary from the (frequently only implicit) full density forecast ([Kolassa, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017)). The only common functional that is additive, and where reconciliation thus makes sense, is the expectation. As such, our reconciliation on a log scale will go a way towards getting us a reconciled unbiased forecast, but only on the log scale. But the back-transformation will break the sum consistency, whether we just use $\exp$ and get a biased back-transform, or include the [bias correction](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html) by including an estimate of the variance.

It may well be that your underlying issue is best addressed through the kind of price scenario analysis described above.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, this actually helps a lot! Will give it some thought and experiment with this approach.

Comment: Btw. do you see a possibility to keep the top level (revenue) forecast fixed while reconciling? This is seems kind of like a top-down approach, but it could still incorporate the forecasts based on the price and volume time series. I briefly thought about "recursive reconciliation" and reusing the original top-level forecasts until the recursion 'converges'.

Comment: Sure. Reconciliation is really a quadratic minimization problem. So if you want to keep certain nodes above or below a certain value (e.g., enforce nonnegativity), this amounts to a quadratic minimization problem with box constraints. And of course, keeping one node fixed is the same as imposing two box constraints on it, one $\leq$ and one $\geq$. I have done so to address fixed planned quantities that should not be modified in the reconciliation. In R, I used to use [`mgcv::pcls()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-33/topics/pcls).