# Computing probabilistic forecasts for a ratio of two other given forecasts

Tags: time-series, forecasting, ratio, probabilistic-forecasts

I have three time series (Revenue, Volume and Price), with Price = Revenue / Volume.

I have created probabilistic forecasts for Revenue and Volume and now need to derive a consistent forecast (including prediction intervals) for the Price time series.

I've used Error Propagation for these kind of cases before (via https://github.com/r-quantities/errors), where I've taken the given intervals for a certain confindence level and computed the ratio.

*Is there a recommended or better way for this problem?* (which occurs whenever on is forecasting ratios, I assume)

This question is related to [Producing 'structurally reconciled' forecasts (e.g. revenue = price * volume)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498781/producing-structurally-reconciled-forecasts-e-g-revenue-price-volume), but investigates a slightly different approach. Rather then reconciling all three timeseries, I'd like to forecast two and derive the third from them.

I've attached a toy-example illustrating the general situation.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)

# forecast ratio
airpass_ratio_tsbl <- as_tsibble((AirPassengers + 400) / AirPassengers)

airpass_ratio_fbl <- airpass_ratio_tsbl %>% 
  model(ets = ETS(value)) %>% 
  forecast()

airpass_ratio_fbl %>% 
  autoplot(airpass_ratio_tsbl)
```

[image]

```r
# forecast basic series
airpass_count_tsbl <- as_tsibble(AirPassengers + 400)
airpass_denom_tsbl <- as_tsibble(AirPassengers)


airpass_count_fbl <- airpass_count_tsbl %>% 
  model(ets = ETS(value)) %>% 
  forecast()

airpass_denom_fbl <- airpass_denom_tsbl %>% 
  model(ets = ETS(value)) %>% 
  forecast()

library(patchwork)
plot_count <- autoplot(airpass_count_fbl, airpass_count_tsbl)
plot_denom <- autoplot(airpass_denom_fbl, airpass_denom_tsbl)

plot_count / plot_denom
```

[image]

```r
# compare forecasts
pred_count_denom <- airpass_count_fbl$.mean / airpass_denom_fbl$.mean
pred_count_denom
#>  [1] 1.917643 1.891572 1.734807 1.854132 1.869472 1.754941 1.714958 1.703860
#>  [9] 1.765008 1.908119 2.020705 1.898877 1.903647 1.879276 1.724877 1.844920
#> [17] 1.861557 1.748765 1.710115 1.700201 1.762379 1.906498 2.020249 1.899600

pred_ratio <- airpass_ratio_fbl$.mean
pred_ratio
#>  [1] 1.885775 1.900048 1.743849 1.769911 1.767676 1.634153 1.532947 1.532352
#>  [9] 1.649004 1.780690 1.938846 1.792032 1.770182 1.782983 1.635852 1.659732
#> [17] 1.657062 1.531359 1.436011 1.434940 1.543618 1.666279 1.813602 1.675646

forecast::accuracy(pred_count_denom, pred_ratio)
#>                  ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE
#> Test set -0.1442346 0.1640471 0.1456945 -8.878111 8.958497

# Forecasts don't match. How to derive probabilistic forecast for the ratio?
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: In general, this is impossible without the joint distribution. Do you have a model for the joint distribution of revenue and volume, or only marginals for each?

Comment: I assume a joint distribution requires a multivariate forecasting model? So far I've been working with univariate forecasts for both series independently, so I guess no.